# How to set a multi-line environment variable on Windows?

Tags: windows, batch-file, environment-variables

I'm trying to set a private SSH key environment variable on Windows. The problem is the private SSH key is in a multiline textfile of the following form:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Line1
Line2
Line3
...
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

I've tried the following script to store the content of the text file in a variable so I can later use it to set an environment variable:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "var="
set LF=^


rem *** Two empty lines are required for the linefeed
FOR /F "delims=" %%a in (private_key.txt) do (
  set "var=!var!!LF!%%a"
)
echo !var!

setx SSH_PRIVATE_KEY !var!
```

This however gives me the following error:

```
ERROR: Invalid syntax. Default option is not allowed more than '2' time(s).
```

Is there another way I can define such an environment variable?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately you left out a very important part of the error you've received, which is the second line in this example:

```
ERROR: Invalid syntax. Default option is not allowed more than '2' time(s).
Type "SETX /?" for usage.
```

if you type `setx /?` you will find the answer, however it is hidden specifically in this line:

```
    SETX /S system /U user /P password  BUILD /K
         "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\
         CurrentVersion\CurrentBuildNumber" /M
```

Note that the above line's `path` contains whitespace and the key here is that the path is double quoted. Your variable also contains whitespace and requires double quoting:

```
setx SSH_PRIVATE_KEY "!var!"
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. This works, however there's a warning: "WARNING: The data being saved is truncated to 1024 characters." When I check the variable I find that it's indeed truncated (doesn't include whole SSH key). Is there a way to circumvent this limitation?

Comment: Yes and no. You can only really adjust it in the registry, but there are still limitations on the tools/software that will read the variable. I would not fiddle with that though. You can split the key into 2 though and use both variables to create one. but I would have just stuck with the file containing the key instead. If you can explain exactly how you plan on using the variable, maybe i can suggest a better solution.

Comment: I'm essentially trying to build a Docker image from a docker-compose.yml file. At a given point the dockerfile needs to clone a git repo and I need the SSH keys to autheticate

Comment: but then just pipe the key from the file then?

Comment: Do you mean the equivalent of SSH_KEY = "$(cat ~/file.txt)" on Windows? How do I go about doing that on Windows?

Comment: well, we're pretty much doing it up to the point where we set `!var!` but once you are doing the `setx` command you're running into a 1024 byte limit. So simply use `!var!` instead. but in all honesty I would then just run powershell command instead `powershell -command '$SSH_KEY = Get-Content .\test.txt'` where `powershell write-host $SSH_KEY` will return the result for testing purpose.